Explain Muslim 2844 and trumpet of israfeel as
Assalamu alaikum.
My question is about the Hadith in Muslim 2844 where some companions of Muhammad saw heard a noise and they went to Muhammad saw and he told them that it's the noise of the rock falling in jahannam. My question is that how did they hear that noise when sound can't even travel through space. The Hadith didn't mention that it's a miracle. I have the same question about the trumpet of israfeel as.
How can this be explained? Please explain my question I've been confused about this for some time. Jazakallahu Khair.

Maybe because they were in presence of the prophet peace and blessing be upon him. Allahualam

Note that the arrangement of hadith collection is rather made by editors not by the author, so if you refer to a hadith # you need to add further information such as the edition, narrator, context etc. (the more information the best it could be identified) you refer to or in best case share the hadith text in your question post.

There is no need for a text to mention something is a miracle for us to assume it is. We can do that for any reasonable reason we want. If an explicit mention was needed, most miracles would be impossible to determine as miracles!
